# Add an onclick widget update to an existing AlarmManager triggered upate

Tags: android, widget, onclick, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I'm new to Android development. I've managed to code a widget which updates every 30 minutes using Alarm Manager.  This part is working correctly.

I now want to also enable manually updating of the widget whenever I click on it (i.e. trigger the same OnReceive() via a broadcast whether via the repeating alarm or the click).

I hoped it would be as simple as adding the two lines at the end (as shown below), but the onClick is not working when I click the widget.  What is the best way to achieve what I am trying to do?

```
@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    super.onEnabled(context);
    AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    //Update after 30 minutes
    am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis()+ 300, 18000000 , pi);

        //Update manually by Clicking widget (this part not working)    
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.my_widget_layout);         
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.layout.my_widget_layout, pi);
```

Comment: What says "time_widget_layout cannot be resolved or is not a field"? Your IDE? I don't even see that in your source.

Comment: Yes, Eclipse is complaining about it (have now updated my post to clarify this).  my_widget_layout is my widget layout in res/layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you mixing of `R.layout.my_widget_layout` and `R.id.my_widget_layout` in your code.

Should notice that Android uses referenced IDs of **`R.id.xyz`** for all the generated widget items while **`R.layout.abc`** for your views (layout)

I anticipated that error was posed on line:

```
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.my_widget_layout, pi);
```

Comment: Thanks, that has fixed the syntax error (updated above) but onclick is still not triggering the widget update.  My main question now is whether you can have two sources of triggers for the OnReceive() method.  (both onClick and AlarmManager)

Comment: Thanks, I got this working by using the message text field in my widget to use the id rahter than layout as you suggested i.e changed the last line above to: remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.message, pi).